# .gitignore files not in a set

Tags: regex, git, set

Is there a way to limit the filetypes tracked by git by specifying a set of acceptable file types in .gitignore?

I want to be able to limit the filetypes commited to my compiled directory. I understand that the parser is not regex but I'd like something like this.

```
!src/(*.js|*.html|*.css)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do

```
src/*
!src/*.js
!src/*.css
!src/*.html
```

Comment: Not true.

src/derp.xx will not be ignored under this rule

Comment: @JRM sorry, I forgot the important ignoring of the other files in the directory.  Edited.